# Finding condition for Adiabaticity

Tags: differentiation, oscillators, differential-equations, adiabatic

I have a differential equation describing a resonator that looks like this:
$$ \frac{d\alpha(t)}{dt} = [j a - b]\alpha(t) + \sqrt b e^{jct}$$ where I can solve it putting: $$\alpha(t) = \alpha e^{jct}$$
in the above eqn. leading to:
$$\alpha = \frac{\sqrt b}{j[a-c]-b}$$
Now, I want to replace $a$ in the first eqn. with $$a = a_0 + a_1cos(d t)$$. Though even then the first differential eqn. can be solved using integrating factor method leading to solution involving Bessel function, I was wondering what should be the relationship between $a_1,d$ and  $d$ so that I can re-write third eqn. as just:
$$\alpha(t) = \frac{\sqrt b}{j[a_0 + a_1 cos(dt)-c]-b}$$
It is usually refererred as Adiabatic condition where the parameter (here, $\alpha(t)$) evolves adiabatically with other variables of the system but I am not sure how to establish the relationship between different variables for it to be true.

Comment: is this even a Hamiltonian system? Are you sure there's something like conservation of adiabatic invariants for this system, which is quite unlike the usual Hamiltonian system.

Comment: Hi @AXensen I am not sure what you meant. It is a differential equation that I am tryin to solve and by deriving the adiabatic condition, I want to know more about the working conditions of the resonator. Under which condition the solution of first differential equation can be written as the last equation is something I desire to get. Kindly let me know if I have made some mistake.

Comment: Okay I just don't know what you're talking about and I'm not equipped to answer this question. I don't know what this "adiabatic condition" thing is. I'm familiar with the conservation of adiabatic invariants, which is something that happens in Hamiltonain systems. If a Hamiltonian for a periodic system changes slowly, the action $\int pdq$ per oscillation period is conserved. But since your system doesn't look to be Hamiltonian, I thought maybe the whole adiabatic thing just doesn't work. But I think you're referring to something else.